# Gii Extension for Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, yii, crud, gii

I need a tool like Gii Extension for Laravel but I can't find it.

This extension provides a Web-based code generator, called Gii, for Yii 2 applications. You can use Gii to quickly generate models, forms, modules, CRUD, etc.

Here is some images:

[image: Gii image]

[image: Gii image]

Comment: Really need something like it for Laravel. But still don't have it yet. Laravel should also focus on automated code generation apart from its rapid development claim.

Answer (score 6):

The closest things I can think of when it comes to model and CRUD generators in Laravel would be:

- The [BackPack suite](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack) especially the [CRUD package](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD)
- The [InfyOm scaffolding generators](http://labs.infyom.com/laravelgenerator/)